# Recrusive function to generate a random string- How to increase char?

Tags: java

I need to create a recrusive function to generate a random string - 
When setting the recrusive as following - the char value - starting from a is not increased - What am i doing wrong?

```
private static String findPasswordTest2(Password p, int length, String testString, char a)
{
    if (p.isPassword(testString))
    {
        return testString;
    }

    if (a!='z')
    {
        findPasswordTest2(p, length, testString, a++);
        findPasswordTest2(p, length, testString+a, a++);
    }

    findPasswordTest2(p, length, testString+a, a);

    if (p.isPassword(testString))
    {
        return testString;
    }

    return "error";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing post-increment , you should do pre-increment.
When using a++ , although increments to the next char , but since it is post increment , it would return the initial value.
Doing in the following manner would give you the desired result :

```
 findPasswordTest2(p,length,testString,++a);
 findPasswordTest2(p,length,testString+a,++a);
```